# Ef Core String Not Contains Excludes Null

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Why is it that when i query in Entity Framework Core for string Not Equals it will give return NULL values (by appending "Or ISNULL(field)"), but when i query for example "not Contains" or "not StartWith" It will not

I know that i can achieve the same result by adding manually to the query to include NULL, my question is why are the 2 behaving differently when it comes to NULL? is there any obvious reason for that?

Code Example:

C# - `dbContext.Employee.Where(x => x.jobNotes != "abc").Select(x => x.firstName).ToList();`

Generated Sql - `exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [x].[firstName] FROM [Employee] AS [x] WHERE  (([x].[jobNotes] <> N''abc'') OR [x].[jobNotes] IS NULL)'`

C# - `dbContext.Employee.Where(x => !x.jobNotes.Contains("abc")).Select(x => x.firstName).ToList();`

Generated Sql - `exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [x].[firstName] FROM [Employee] AS [x] WHERE (CHARINDEX(N''abc'', [x].[jobNotes]) <= 0)'`

Comment: What you're asking is "why did the EF Core team decide to make this specific implementation decision" and, unfortunately, unless someone present is a core team member, any answer is speculation.  It might be worth opening an issue on the EF Core repo to get clarity.

Comment: Well, it just makes sence. NULL is not "Hello World", so include NULLS if i query "everything BUT "Hello World"".
But NULL will never contain anything nor will it start with a string. So exclude it from my results.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the LINQ(?) statements you have in your C# code and the generated SQL statements you get. Then explain where you want (or not want) any `ISNULL()` statement and why.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is not "obviously", but it can be explained somehow:

Having the C# expression:

```
x.jobNotes.Contains("abc")
```

only "works", when the value of `x.JobNotes` is not `NULL`, otherwise you would get a `NullReferenceException`. To ensure that you don't, only `NOT NULL` values are checked. The generated SQL statement

```
(CHARINDEX(N''abc'', [x].[jobNotes]) <= 0)
```

does that because for any `NULL` values in the `jobNotes` table, the result of `CHARINDEX` will be `NULL`, as defined in the [documentation of `CHARINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> If either the *expressionToFind* or *expressionToSearch* expression has a NULL value, CHARINDEX returns NULL.

Comparing `NULL` values in this case (`NULL <= 0`) results in `UNKNOWN`, as defined in the [documentations of comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> When SET ANSI_NULLS is ON, an operator that has one or two NULL expressions returns UNKNOWN. When SET ANSI_NULLS is OFF, the same rules apply, except for the equals (=) and not equals (<>) operators. When SET ANSI_NULLS is OFF, these operators treat NULL as a known value, equivalent to any other NULL, and only return TRUE or FALSE (never UNKNOWN).

I'm not sure what `WHERE UNKNOWN` would do as you cannot run this expression directly, but as an example the expression `WHERE NULL <= 0` results in `WHERE FALSE`, which means the row with the `jobNotes` column set to `NULL` is not returned.

When you look at the query from the C# or Entity Framework standpoint, it does make sense that these `NULL` values are not returned. When you have a query like

```
dbContext.Employee
    .Where(x => !x.jobNotes.Contains("abc"))
    .Select(x => x.firstName)
    .ToList()
```

and you get entities where the `jobNotes` column is `NULL`, the question arise:

> "Wait, why is `jobNotes` NULL? It should have thrown a `NullReferenceException` because of the `Contains()` method call."

So, that *might* be the reason why it does not return rows where the `jobNotes` column has the value `NULL` (and works "differently" with `x.jobNotes != "abc"`).

Comment: Make sense as with linq to entities you would actually get a NullReferenceException for not contains if it null but not equals of course works, but its still interesting because in the case of linq to sql  "Contains" is really just passed down to sql and sql will be able to handle it and return nulls

Comment: But the question is, if it should return rows with `NULL` values, when `x.jobNotes.Contains()` would result in an NullReferenceException. Looks like it doesn't to be consistent.

Comment: I believe that in the case of "linq to sql" the statement `x.jobNotes.Contains()` would never be evaluated in c# instead c# will convert it to sql and let sql do the evaluation (maybe i am wrong on that) so it shouldn't result in a NullReferenceException